# Can there be two return types in a C function?

Tags: objective-c, c

I am looking at a [project](https://github.com/briskml/brisk) which aims expose Cocoa API's to OCaml. The code comprises of a function which has two values where return type is mentioned.

```
CAMLprim value ml_NSWindow_center(value win_v)
{
  CAMLparam1(win_v);
  NSWindow *win = NSWindow_val(win_v);
  [win center];
  CAMLreturn(Val_unit);
}
```

Is that possible ? or that is not a return type.

Comment: It's not possible for a function to return two values (of different or same type). My guess is that one active `#define` is used to change that `CAMLprim` to some compiler flag (or maybe nothing).

Comment: @pmg is correct - see https://www.linux-nantes.org/~fmonnier/OCaml/ocaml-wrapping-c.html

Comment: `cmd+ctrl+click` on `CAMLreturn` and `CAMLprim` and you will see what is it.

Comment: Very odd name for type: `value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CAMLprim` seems not to be a type at all, but a linkage/storage class for the function - it seems to be `#define`d to empty strings in some headers that I found. The real return type is `value`, which is a `typedef` for an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://www.linux-nantes.org/~fmonnier/OCaml/ocaml-wrapping-c.html), for any function with the return as `CAMLprim value`

> This function must have return type CAMLprim value and its parameter type has to be value. All parameters given to C functions from OCaml are of type value. The include header  provides conversion macros to convert the type value to C native types. In this case to convert to a C integer, that macro is Int_val(). **Then as the return value of the OCaml function is unit, the C function have to return a unit, which is done with the macro Val_unit.**